# How to define a callback function to receive TCP/IP data stream in MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab, callback, matlab-guide, tcp, matlab-gui

I wrote the following simple GUI to do that but still the callback function (RXDATA) does not execute at all that I want to use to receive data from the remote computer.

```
function com_test_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to com_test (see VARARGIN)
handles.t_rzm = tcpip('169.254.181.51', 51000);
set(handles.t_rzm,'ByteOrder','littleEndian');
fopen(handles.t_rzm);
handles.t_rzm.BytesAvailableFcn = @RXDATA;
% Choose default command line output for com_test
handles.output = hObject;
% the remote computer is sending the data
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
function RXDATA(hObject, eventdata, handles) % The callback function supposed to get data
% handles = guidata(hObject);
disp('yes')
dum_PB_Callback(handles.dum_PB,event,dat)
guidata(handles.dum_PB,handles) %% function ends
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

This is the subroutine function to send a command to the application in the remote PC to choose a data item

I also defined a dummy push button to trigger the RXDATA function but it does not help.

```
% --- Executes on button press in dum_PB. (Dummy Push Button)
function dum_PB_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to dum_PB (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
disp('dum_PB_Callback')
% if handles.UserData.sync==1
handles.t_rzm.BytesAvailableFcn = @RXDATA;
% end
guidata(hObject,handles) %% dummy button function ends
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see your problem.
I will emphasis Wrong or Add code.

Check below Code.

```
handles.t_rzm = tcpip('169.254.181.51', 51000);

set(handles.t_rzm,'ByteOrder','littleEndian');

handles.t_rzm.BytesAvailableCnt = (Your Data Size)

handles.t_rzm.BytesAvailableMode = (Your Data Type)

handles.t_rzm.BytesAvailableFcn = @RXDATA;

fopen(handles.t_rzm);
```

and

```
function RXDATA(hObject, eventdata) // ← Only 2 Parameters
```

and  then whenever receive data, Callback the RXDATA function.

If you want to use parameter such as handles,

```
handles.t_rzm.BytesAvailableFcn = {@RXDATA,handles};
```

and then

```
function RXDATA(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```